# How to reduce computation time for a large symbolic matrix

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction, data

I have a 6x6 matrix (**A**) that is a function of ***k*** and ***H*** with complex symbolic entries that contain functions. I want to reduce the computational time since I will be evaluating the matrix many times for an integral that I need to compute later down the track. The code is shown below.

```
Clear[ω, σ, γ, L, Ms, A, α, ωM, ωH, k, \[ScriptCapitalK], d, s, dp, μ0, H, j, q]

ω = 2*Pi*19*10^9; 
σ = 4.5*10^6*4; 
γ = 2*Pi*2.867*10^6; 
L = 30/(10^7*10^2); 
Ms = 17900; 
A = 1.3/10^10; 
α = (A/Ms^2)*8*Pi; 
ωM = γ*Ms; 
ωH[H_] := γ*H
μ0 = (4*Pi)/10^7; 
d = 0.0016; 

\[ScriptCapitalK][k_] = Sqrt[k^2 + ω*σ*μ0*I]; 
q[i_, k_, H_] := 
  Root[(-I)*k*μ0*σ*ω*ωM^2 - 
     I*k^3*α*μ0*σ*ω*ωM^2 + 
     k^2*ω*ωM*#1 + 
     I*μ0*σ*ω^2*ωM*#1 - k*ω^2*#1^2 + 
           k^3*α*ωM^2*#1^2 + 
     k^5*α^2*ωM^2*#1^2 + 
     I*k*α*μ0*σ*ω*ωM^2*#1^2 - 
     k*α*ωM^2*#1^4 - 2*k^3*α^2*ωM^2*#1^4 + 
           k*α^2*ωM^2*#1^6 + 
     k*ω^2*\[ScriptCapitalK][k]^2 - 
     k^3*α*ωM^2*\[ScriptCapitalK][k]^2 - 
     k^5*α^2*ωM^2*\[ScriptCapitalK][
        k]^2 - ω*ωM*#1*\[ScriptCapitalK][k]^2 + 
           k*α*ωM^2*#1^2*\[ScriptCapitalK][k]^2 + 
     2*k^3*α^2*ωM^2*#1^2*\[ScriptCapitalK][k]^2 - 
     k*α^2*ωM^2*#1^4*\[ScriptCapitalK][k]^2 - 
     I*k*μ0*σ*ω*ωM*ωH[H] + 
           k*ωM*#1^2*ωH[H] + 
     2*k^3*α*ωM*#1^2*ωH[H] - 
     2*k*α*ωM*#1^4*ωH[H] - 
     k*ωM*\[ScriptCapitalK][k]^2*ωH[H] - 

     2*k^3*α*ωM*\[ScriptCapitalK][k]^2*ωH[H] + 
     2*k*α*ωM*#1^2*\[ScriptCapitalK][k]^2*ωH[
       H] + k*#1^2*ωH[H]^2 - 
     k*\[ScriptCapitalK][k]^2*ωH[H]^2 & , i];

 mx[i_, k_, H_, y_] := M[i]*E^(y*q[i, k, H])
my[i_, k_, H_, 
  y_] := -(I k mx[i, k, H, 
      y] (k^2 α ωM q[i, k, H]^2 - α ωM q[
         i, k, H]^4 - ωM \[ScriptCapitalK][k]^2 - 
           k^2 α ωM \[ScriptCapitalK][
             k]^2 + α ωM q[i, k, H]^2 \[ScriptCapitalK][
             k]^2 + q[i, k, H]^2 ωH[H] - \[ScriptCapitalK][
             k]^2 ωH[H]))/(-I μ0 σ ω ωM q[
           i, k, H] + k ω q[i, k, H]^2 - 
         k ω \[ScriptCapitalK][k]^2 + ωM q[i, k, 
           H] \[ScriptCapitalK][k]^2)
    hx[i_, k_, H_, 
      y_] := (μ0 σ ω my[i, k, H, y] q[i, k, 
        H] + (k mx[i, k, H, y] + 
         I my[i, k, H, y] q[i, k, H]) \[ScriptCapitalK][k]^2)/(
     k (q[i, k, H]^2 - \[ScriptCapitalK][k]^2))
    hy[i_, k_, H_, y_] := (
     I (k hx[i, k, H, y] + k mx[i, k, H, y]) - my[i, k, H, y] q[i, k, H])/
     q[i, k, H]

    s = 0; 
    BoundaryConditionFree[k_, H_, y_] := 
     Evaluate[{Sum[
        hy[i, k, H, y] + 
         my[i, k, H, y] + (I*hx[i, k, H, y]*k)/Abs[k], {i, 1, 6}]}]
    BoundaryConditionDielectric[k_, H_, y_] := 
         Evaluate[{Sum[(hy[i, k, H, y] + my[i, k, H, y])*
           Coth[Abs[k]*(d + s)] - hx[i, k, H, y]*((Abs[k]*I)/k), {i, 1, 
          6}]}]; 

j = 1; 
dp = 0; 
mxExchangeBoundaryCondition[k_, H_] := 
  D[Sum[mx[i, k, H, y], {i, 1, 6}], y] + 
   dp*Sum[mx[i, k, H, y], {i, 1, 6}]; 
myExchangeBoundaryCondition[k_, H_] := 
  D[Sum[my[i, k, H, y], {i, 1, 6}], y] + 
   dp*Sum[my[i, k, H, y], {i, 1, 6}]; 

Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
CCompilers[]
\[ScriptCapitalA] = Compile[{{k, _Real}, {H, _Real}}, 
       Evaluate[
    Normal[CoefficientArrays[
       Join[{mxExchangeBoundaryCondition[k, H] /. y -> 0}, 
                 {mxExchangeBoundaryCondition[k, H] /. 
          y -> L}, {myExchangeBoundaryCondition[k, H] /. y -> 0}, 
                 {myExchangeBoundaryCondition[k, H] /. y -> L}, 
        BoundaryConditionDielectric[k, H, 0], 
        BoundaryConditionFree[k, H, L]], 
               {M[1], M[2], M[3], M[4], M[5], M[6]}][[2]]]], 
   Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

I've looked after the usual suspects i.e. ensuring machine precision numbers are used, functions are compiled in C and parallelization is enabled. However it still takes 0.312s to compute ***A***.

MATLAB does this calculation almost instantly. I don't want to use it down the track though as I will need to make symbolic adjustments which will be time consuming.

Comment: And the code?...

Comment: Posted. I'm pretty new to posting on stack exchange so not sure how to post the raw input from Mathematica. Will look it up now.

Comment: Done. It looks messy, its only because I have used alot of script notation.

Comment: You did not define `M`

Comment: M is produced by the function mx and is unknown. A is a matrix of coefficients of M, If you copy and paste this code, it should run fine? It runs fine for me.

Comment: Apologies, should have been clear. The matrix is \[ScriptCapitalA]. Try evaluating \[ScriptCapitalA][1000, 21.86] // Timing. You can evaluate A at any k and H value, doesn't have to be 1000 and 21.86.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not getting that error and A should be a 6x6 matrix not a single value. What is your evaluation time without compilation?

Comment: What happens when you do `Clear[M]` and then evaluate? Do you get error messages from the evaluation of \\[ScriptCapitalA][1000, 21.86]?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I haven't cleared `M`, but suddenly the errors are gone. :/

Comment: A thousand iterations: uncompiled: `81.7369`, compiled `81.619s`. No errors. So clearly not much improvement there.

Comment: Yeah, mine has little to no difference between compiled and uncompiled as well, both at about 0.312s for a single iteration. I get improvements when iterating with parallel table, but still MUCH slower than MATLAB. This is my issue :S.